# I'm using Wpf C# and I have a couple of windows, how can I link code behind form one window to other code behind window

Tags: c#, wpf

So I want to get a value from a textbox in my mainwindow and put it in a calculation for a code behind in another window, how can I take data from Mainwindow input and use it in a code behind of another window

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest reading into MVVM pattern, that would help you out a lot in achieving this in a nice and clean way.

However if you want a quick, dirty hack, just make a new Static Class somewhere with Static Properties like `public static string Window1Text {get; set;}` and that should be visible from all your windows.